# List Item background stretched 9patch Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment, nine-patch, android-styles

Im trying to create a 9patch background in my listview items, but since I modified the images with 9patch the background is streched so I cannot see the whole image. 
Here is the image that I've modified:

[image]

Here is my item.xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my toggle selector that is showing the proper image depending on the list item state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_normal"></item>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected"></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_normal"></item>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected"></item>
    <item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@drawable/item_normal"></item>
    <item android:state_active="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected"></item>
     <item android:state_active="false" android:drawable="@drawable/item_normal"></item>
</selector>
```

but instead of the full image in the background I'm gettings this:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Looking at it, I believe your 9patch is incorrect. Have you tried inspecting it with `draw9patch` or a similar tool?

Comment: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html create nine patch image here

Comment: `Does anyone know how can I fix this?` **YES**! What is your desired result? **1** - the circle must become a round rectangle and **contain the text** (harder) OR **2** - the circle remains untouched and acts like a **bullet** (easier)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Ninepatch Image Like Below....
That could be useful to you...........
i could not remove lines of Corners So **IGNORE IT...**

Note that black line is used for image streching.......
Here...

Left _top : is used for streaching image.....
Right-Bottom  : is used for Setting content area where your text will set...

[image]